# Are There set in stones rules for EDA?

Tags: data-cleaning, feature-engineering, preprocessing

so I'm doing my first Data Science project and I'm having doubts in EDA and data preprocessing.

There are several preprocess that I want to do, these are:

- dealing outliers
- dealing with missing values, i want to use mean value
- dealing with imbalanced data
- removing features that have low correlation towards the target variable (if exist)
- dealing with highly correlated features

but I'm having doubt on which should i do first and which one should i do later.

for example, if i deal with outliers first, then impute the missing value with mean, it will certainly yield a different result than if i impute missing value with mean then dealing with the outliers.

I searched across the internet, and no one seems to give a throughout guide on this process.

Also, is it true that its best practice to split the data first, then do preprocess on training set? if that's so, then why i often found people to standardize the test set?

Comment: If you have doubts about the order of steps in your initial data analysis, may I suggest you conduct experiments where the order of operation(s) is changed? If you consider yourself a scientist, then experiment! Satisfy your curiosity. A 'roadmap' for EDA, I don't believe I have seen such a thing. A roadmap that Everyone uses? Maybe yr experiments will bear one out? ;)

Comment: woah thanks for the motivation. I find it weird that nobody has make a guide for EDA or data preprocessing. given that it is the most crucial step in DS or DL